# Is it possible to use two Facebook apps on the same page, or alternatively merge them into one?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

**UPDATE: fixed by exporting the facebook comments from the first app and importing them as wordpress comments, unfortunately haven't been able to import them back into the new facebook comments yet.**

Once upon a time our company made the poor decision to use one Facebook app for the comments plugin on our blog, and a separate one to handle posting to OpenGraph. Now we are trying to setup our blog to post 'read' actions when people read our content and running into the problem that we can't use two different Facebook applications on the same page. So my question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to merge our two applications so we don't have to either lose all the comments on our blog to use OpenGraph, or lose the OpenGraph actions we've recorded and keep our comments.
2. Is there some way I haven't found to connect to two separate Facebook Apps on the same page

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could always merge one into the other, but you'd have to likely rebuild things to make functions from one work with the other on top of what the other is currently doing. You could build a 3rd app thats a port of the 2 so you can leave the first 2 running while your rebuild on the 3rd launching the 3rd and taking the other 2 down when its ready.

But connecting one from the other is out of the question as if memory serves facebook apps are sandboxed and can't communicate one to the other via facebook. They can use the same server, same database etc and can manipulate one another on the back end from the server level of the server they live on.

But in all it boils down to what your doing, how they currently work and all else. with that theres no easy answer, and nothing like dropping one set of files on top of the other and hoping it works.

Your either stuck with how they are, or rebuilding to one extent or another to bring them together unforunately

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just exporting all the comments from one app and importing them into the other app.